# Equivalent to ContentInset for UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a function where there will be a somewhat permanent banner on top of my `UITabBar` from my TabBarController. To avoid ruining the content in the `viewController.view` I would like to use some kind of content-inset. 
If all the viewControllers of the tabBarController were tableViews or scrollViews, then I could change their contentInset, but not all of them are. 
I have tried changing the viewController.view.frame to have a shorter height (to make room for a 44px banner below view and above tabBar), but the view won't update. I'm guessing it doesn't like the idea of the 44px 'void' in the viewController itself (as nothing is below the UIView).

I have thought of a few different ways:

1. Somehow changing the height/origin of the actual `TabBar` without changing the design, making 44px extra room at the top of the tabBar, which would hopefully update the 'above' viewController's constraints
2. Somehow edit the viewController.view's constraints to give space between the TabBar and the bottom of the view.
3. Somehow change the BottomLayoutGuide programmatically

Are any of these possible? I have searched, without any luck.. Are there any other ways of doing this to a general `UIViewController`?

To clarify, I do have own classes for each of the ViewControllers in the TabBarController, but I would like to find a way of achieving this without having to change any code of the viewControllers. -> I want to make this change solely from the UITabBarController. (eg. (pseudo) self.viewControllers.view.frame.size.height -= 44; (not actually code, shortened)(which doesn't work))

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use `bounds` property of `UIView` to do the trick. This is how I would do this:

**Step 1 :** Add a category on `UIViewController` to change the view controller's view down by passed in points:

**UIViewController.MyAddition.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIViewController (MyAddition)

- (void)moveViewDownBy:(CGFloat)iDownPoints;

@end
```

**UIViewController.MyAddition.m**

```
#import "UIViewController+MyAddition.h"

@implementation UIViewController (MyAddition)


- (void)moveViewDownBy:(CGFloat)iDownPoints {
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    bounds.origin.y -= iDownPoints;
    bounds.size.height = -iDownPoints;
    self.view.bounds = bounds;
}

@end
```

**Step 2 :** Call this category on your `ViewController`'s `loadView` method:

```
[self moveViewDownBy:<Height_Of_Your_Top_Banner>];
```

Comment: It seems like this works for changing the origin of the content, but if I change your code to use `bounds.size.height` instead of `bounds.origin.y`, it doesn't work.. I'm not a constraint-guru, so perhaps my issue now is that the constraints are holding the bounds back?

Comment: Take a look at my updated method. I believe that is what you are looking for. @Sti

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'm not trying to 'move' the view at all. I am only trying to make it shorter. I have tried your method and removed the origin.y-change, but it seems I'm not allowed to change the bounds.size.height. Nothing happens AT ALL when I change `self.view.bounds.size.height`. I know it works with regular subViews, but since it is the primary view (viewController.view/self.view) I don't think I'm allowed to change it.

Comment: For instance, in a viewController's `viewDidLoad`, if I write the following: `CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds; bounds.size.height -= 200; self.view.bounds = bounds;`, then that should display a gap at the bottom of `self.view`, but it doesn't.. It feels like the *size* of my self.view is unchangable..

Comment: Try `bounds.size.height = -200;`.

Comment: Hm.. interesting.. That somehow almost works.. I can't understand why.. It looks somewhat similar to setting the origin.y. Now to the next problem, I don't want the content to move down. I want it to 'move up'. I need a gap between the view and the bottom of the screen. I've tried bounds.size.height = 200 (negative value of yours, making it positive), then nothing happens again.. I'm looking into if it has something to do with autoresizingMask now..

Comment: If you think my suggestion helped, please up vote. I've to call it a day. Good luck with your fix. Please post the findings for enlightenment!

Comment: The sample `UITextView` I have inside one of my UIViews is constrained to meet the `Bottom Layout Guide`. Without this changing its location, I'm guessing nothing can happen..

Answer (score 0):

You can't change height of a viewController's frame.Because it's height/width is readonly

So,do with this tricky

```
CGRect frame = self.viewControllers.view.frame;
frame.size.height -=44;
self.viewControllers.view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I see now that I wrote wrong. This is exactly what I did, but it doesn't work. It seems like it's impossible to change the height for viewController.view. See it this way, if you changed the viewController.view's frame to be 100px in height, what would be visible below that point? Blackness? I still haven't been able to shorten it..